# Plotting net delta of calls and puts

Tags: options, market-data, greeks, delta-hedging, delta

I'm plotting the Net Delta of calls and puts for a given ticker symbol and a user specified range of expiration dates. Net Delta is calculated for each option contract using the following formula:

`Net Delta = 100 * Delta * Open Interest`

The x-axis is strike price and the y-axis is net deltas. Here is an example using SPY with a date range of 1/16/2024 to 1/17/2024:

[image]

In order to reduce the noise on the chart I have incorporated filters, one of which being a range of deltas. For example, if the user selects a delta range of 0-0.25 (-0.25 for puts) then contracts that don't fall within that range will be filtered out and not plotted.

This is where I'm unsure how to parse the data. Consider this example -- let's say a date range consisting of 5 unique expiration dates is selected. The 100 strike call expiring on x date has a delta of 0.15 -- so this contract is added to the plot. But the 100 strike call expiring on n date has a delta of 0.55.

My question is this: because I am plotting by strike price should I incorporate all option contracts for a given strike if just one contract meets the delta filter? Or only plot the data that meets the filter?

I might be overthinking this but I am currently plotting ALL contracts if one contract makes the cut. My reasoning is that if a given strike price is displayed on the chart then all data for that strike price should be displayed, not cherry picked. But I also want the data to be useful and accurate -- if only 1 out 20 contracts meets the filter and I'm plotting 19 other data sets that don't meet the criteria perhaps that's not an accurate representation of the data?

Thoughts?